# Bootstrap three columns with dynamicaly inserted image

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, laravel-blade

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

But this is the result I get:

[image]

The img and text are inserted from the DB. This is the code:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 8rem;">
   @foreach ($rooms as $room)
       <div class="col-4" data-category="{{ $room->data_category}}">
            <a href="#zoomImg{{ $room->id }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#zoomImg{{ $room->id }}">
                <img src="{{ $room->img }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">                        
            </a>
            <div class="text-left mt-3 mb-5">
                <p class="product-subtitle">{{ $room->name }}</p>
                <h4 class="product-title">Shop the Look</h4>
                <a class="product-price-link" href="#getPriceByRoom{{ $room->id }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#getPriceByRoom{{ $room->id }}">get price</a>
           </div>
      </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

I tried positioning the @foreach in a different way and still could't get the result I wanted. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to the layout on [this article](https://jsbin.com/cebego/1/edit?html,output)

```
.masonry-container {
 column-count: 3;
 column-gap: 15px;
}
.masonry-item {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
}
.masonry-item img {
 display:block;
 width: 100%;
}
```